# Is the analogread function averaging the samples taken by the ADC?

Tags: adc, serial

In many development boards the analog voltage data which is sampled by the ADC can be sent to the serial port. But the data speed I see on the serial port by HyperTerminal or Serial monitor is much slower than the sampling rate.

Lets take Arduino as an example. As far as I understand the analogread() function samples an analog input at 10kHz rate. It means 10000 samples taken per second.

But when I use the Serial Monitor it seems the data speed which we see as upcoming/flowing line by line per second on Serial Monitor is much slower.

Is that because the analogread() is averaging the samples before the data is sent to the serial port?

Comment: [`analogRead()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogRead) doesn't send the samples anywhere. I think you need to look at some example code and then revisit your question.

Comment: ok i edited to: "Is that because the analogread() is averaging the samples before the data is sent to the serial port?"

Comment: That function only reads the ADC value, it doesn't do anything else. The 10KHz you mention is related to how often you can call that function, it has nothing to do with what the rest of the code is doing with that data.

Comment: "In many development boards the analog voltage data which is sampled by the ADC can be sent to the serial port" I've yet to see one that does this unless you write a program to do so. "Lets take Arduino as an example" So are you talking generally or just Arduino? Since this is a software question the answer will depend on the exact software used.

Comment: It *can* sample at 10kHz, doesnt mean it does. When you analogRead and serialPrint, it does it once and prints once. If you want some sort of running average you have to implement it, there's nothing obscure running in the background.

Comment: @WesleyLee No indeed I dont want averaging. But when I see the readings in Serial Monitor it is much much slower rate. Let me put it this way. If I use a watch and start and stop sampling for 1 second I must have at least 10000 sampled data by the ADC. But the serial monitor shows muc much less lines than that. Why is that happening?

Comment: Given a sample frequency is 10kHz. Assumed the ADC is 8-bit. You'll need to transfer et-least 800kbit or 100kB a second. Because serial is much slower then the ADC you won't get the 10kHz sample rate until the communication can keep up.

Comment: So what do I see at the Serial Monitor then? It is not all the samples, it is not the average. It is what then? :(

Comment: We can't tell what you are seeing on the Serial Monitor because that varies from firmware to firmware. I'll repeat myself: if you use analogRead then Serial.print in a loop, you *are* seeing all the samples.

Comment: @WesleyLee thanks for the last clarification. that was what i was asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a loop that calls analogRead() to take a reading, and then serialPrint() to send the reading, each pass through the loop will take at least the sum of the time for those two functions calls together.

When you first call serialPrint(), it returns in uS, as it doesn't actually *send* data, but puts it into the 64 deep transmit buffer, to be sent in the background. If the transmit buffer is emptying slower than you are filling it (at 9600 baud, it's sending roughly one character per mS, so you can send at most 100 off 10 character messages per second) then eventually when called, it will find not enough space in the transmit buffer for the whole message, and will *Block*, that is not return, until there is enough space. Each call to serialPrint() will now take 10mS (assuming 10 characters at 9600 baud). That's what slows your loop down.

To send faster, choose a higher baud rate, and reduce the number of characters in the message.

Comment: void loop()

{

  val = analogRead(analogPin);    // read the input pin

  Serial.println(val);             // debug value

}

Comment: it is sad that using analogread as above code in a loop we will never know the exact sampling rate right?

Comment: The sampling period is the time it takes for a loop to complete. So the rate would be 1/looptime.

Comment: @WesleyLee last question. can we trust each loop time will ve equal? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure since I don't know how Arduino deals with jamming stuff on its serial buffer.

Comment: I've told you, it has a 64 long buffer, it returns fast when there's buffer available, it blocks when there isn't. I had my 'scope on a debug pin last week timing a serialPrint(), so I know which orifice I'm talking out of!

Comment: @user16307: “_Can we trust each loop time will be equal?_” No, you can't. Sending “1000” takes longer than sending “999”: one more byte to send. And then there is the timer 0 interrupting your code roughly every millisecond: each time it's interrupted, the loop takes ≈ 6.25 µs longer to complete (assuming an AVR-based Arduino). If you want constant sampling rate, forget `analogRead()` and read the datasheet: the ADC can be auto-triggered by a timer, or even by itself (free running mode).

Answer (score 4):

> As far as I understand the analogread() function samples an analog input at 10kHz rate.

No, it samples an analog input at *once per invocation*. This means that if it is run 10000 times within a second (assuming it can be run that many times within a second) then *the code* is sampling at 10kHz. But if it's run only twice per second then the code is sampling at 2Hz.

Comment: Let me ask the same question to you. When I see the readings in Serial Monitor it is much much slower rate. Let me put it this way. If I use a watch and start and stop sampling for 1 second I must have at least 10000 sampled data by the ADC. But the serial monitor shows much much less lines than that. Why is that happening?

Comment: Because your understanding of how `analogRead()` works is completely and irredeemably broken.

Comment: @user16307 -- "If I use a watch and start and stop sampling for 1 second I must have at least 10000 sampled data by the ADC" That assumption is wrong to begin with, any reasoning based on that will be wrong.

Comment: If during that second you call analogRead once, you will have one sample.

Comment: Imagine analogread is in a loop and sampling 5kHz per second. Now we use a watch and start and stop sampling for 1 second. At the serial monitor you will see much much less lines of voltage readings. But actually the samples are 5000

Comment: You get **one sample per call. Ever. Always.**